# Import a video file and play it (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

How can I import a file in and play it with the `video` element?

I want to import a video file (on the page) and a video element would pop up.

```html
<input type="file">

<h3>What would be imported video:</h3>
<video width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

If you have any questions, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like one wants to upload a video to a server and then play it?

Comment: One will need to upload the video using WebSockets unless one would like the page to reload. If one can reload the page, one may use php or a post processor like it to return a new page with the newly uploaded file ready to play, if one wants the page to not reload then one will need to do complex websocketry and coordinate with javascript to modify the video element once the server has the video file ready.

Comment: Maybe take a look here to get started thinking about this: https://developpaper.com/sync-player-using-websocket-to-play-video-synchronously-in-different-places/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to inform you, `BigBuckBunny.mp4` is an **enormous** video and it'd take much computer CPU to load.

The below code gives you an `<input type=file>` input that accepts `mpeg`, `mp4`, `mp2` and `avi`. You can make it accept anything, or any video with [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).
It takes the video as a `Blob`, passes the `Blob` to a `FileReader` and reads it as a Data URL. Then, it adds a `<source src="the_url">` inside the video.

```js
function loadVideo() {
  // 'input' is the <input> element
  // 'video' is the <video> element
  // 'fs' is a FileReader, to read 'input'
  const input = document.getElementById("input"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    fs = new FileReader;
  // Executes when finished reading; it's asynchronous
  fs.onload = () => {
    // Update video src to the Data URL
    video.innerHTML = `<source src="${fs.result}">\nYour browser does not support HTML5 videos.`;
  }
  // Data URL is data:video/mpeg,base64;AAAAA.....
  fs.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
Upload video: <input id="input" type="file" accept=".avi, .mpeg, .mp2, .mp4" onchange="loadVideo()">
<hr>
<video id="video" controls width="320"></video>
```

##### Edit for [@tinkerer9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19719855/tinkerer9)

> Thanks! How do I make this work for `mov` files too? Adding `.mov` in the `accept` attribute doesn't work.
> [[Link to comment]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129706019)

1. Try to set the `accept` attribute to `.avi, .mpeg, .mp2, .mp4, .mov`
2. Try to remove the `accept` attribute
3. Check if your browser supports `.mov` files
4. Check if the `.mov` file you want to upload is coded right and can be played

Comment: Thanks! How do I make this work for `mov` files too? Adding `.mov` in the `accept` attribute doesn't work.